# How to enable IMCE in a field of a custom block

Tags: blocks, files, plugins, 8

I have module that generates a plugin block with a field of type managed_file.

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    // todo make this IMCE
    $form['background'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Background'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter background image'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['background'])?$config['background']:'',
      '#upload_location' => 'public://backgrounds',
      '#weight' => '2',
    );
}
```

I guess I have to create a `module.schema.yml` file to do that but I don't know how to enable the IMCE.

```
block.settings.stingray_basic_block:
  type: block_settings
  label: 'Stingray basic block'
  mapping:
    body:
      type: text
      label: 'Body'
      translatable: true
    background:
      type: managed_file
      labe: 'Background'
      ??? MAKE IT IMCE ???
```

Usually this boolean appears in the `core.entity_form_display...yml` file as a third party settings structure:

```
content:
  field_background:
    weight: 1
    settings:
      preview_image_style: thumbnail
      progress_indicator: throbber
    third_party_settings:
      imce:
        enabled: true
    type: image_image
```

...but I don't know if it can be set in the `schema.yml` file nor how.

Anyone has info on this?

ref: https://www.drupal.org/node/2821710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an alternative URL input(type=text) for IMCE integration.

You just need to include drupal.imce.input library and set the input class name as "imce-url-input". Also see imce.input.js file

```
if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('imce') && \Drupal\imce\Imce::access()) {
  $form['background'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Background URL'),
    '#attached' => array('library' => array('imce/drupal.imce.input')),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('imce-url-input')),
    '#default_value' => isset($this->configuration['background']) ? $this->configurati‌​on['background'] : '',
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes that works! I would consider this a workaround because we don't get the usual widget with the thumbnail. Also note that in your code it is missing the first `{` on line one. Also note that you also need `'#default_value' => isset($this->configuration['background'])?$this->configuration['background']:'',` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions i've found suggest adding a textfield which means you then have to get the FID from the URI in order to update the file field manually which is much too fussy.

To add the IMCE file browser to an existing managed file field in a custom form, adding the following to the element works for me in Drupal 10:

```
$form['existing_managed_file_field']['#process'][] = ['Drupal\imce\ImceFileField', 'processWidget'];
$form['existing_managed_file_field']['#file_value_callbacks'][] = ['Drupal\imce\ImceFileField', 'setWidgetValue'];
$form['existing_managed_file_field']['#scheme'] = 'public';
```